# Named range as column heading in excel 'table'

Tags: microsoft-excel

It seems to me that it is not possible for a 'table' (meaning excel's table tool) column heading to be equal to a named range.
Take the below example. My table is in cells B3:D6 (i.e. I put that data in those cells, then went Insert > Table  > 'My table has headings'.

In cell F4 I have a named range 'name_person', who's value is 'Person'.

[image]

If I now try to set cell B3 as '=name_person', it just returns '0'. Does anyone know if it is possible to set the table column name to a named range?

[image]

Thanks!
Alyssa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Excel, as far as I am aware, you cannot have formulas as a table header.

You can only have static text as a header.  You can see this if you first set up just data, using your named range reference, then convert to a table:

[image]